# javascript regexp. Replace all except word

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Hello i have a class with elements

```
<div class="help_1"></div>
<div class="onemoreclass help_2 twoclass"></div>
<div class="test help_3"></div>
<div class="class1 help_4"></div>
```

how can i extract only help_(*) matches with javascript?

Comment: $(t.currentTarget).attr('class').replace(/../g, '') is my situation

Comment: You want to extract the string? Or you want to select elements that have a class beginning with that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for straight javascript working against the attribute class (assuming you're not using jQuery and can locate the elements in question via DOM)

```
// Contains array of matches or null if none found
var matches= classAttr.match(/(help_\w)/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution requires the jQuery library:

```
var A = [];
$('div').each(function(){
  var B = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
  for(var i=0;i<B.length;i++){
    var C = B[i];
    if( /^help_/.test(C) ){
      A.push(C);
    }
  }
});

console.log(A);
```

Comment: Your answer needs to explain that this requires the jQuery library. It's also only two identifiers away from not requiring the jQuery library.

Comment: this is really nice with split() but not regexp ? Or it's impossible with regexp ?

Comment: @mindsupport: Why are you married to Regular Expressions? Why do you think that you need Regular Expressions for the space? Rustam is using them for the search for `help_` so you're covered if for some silly reason you feel you _must_ use Regular Expressions.

Comment: i think regexp faster than iteration through elements

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, and app is full of dynamic content with javascript

Comment: It's just more simple then with only one regexp and .match. Regexp in any language are slower then simple string operators

Comment: @mindsupport: You've jumped to the conclusion that the only alternative is iteration through elements, and saying the words "regexp" and "faster" next to each other is almost always equivalent to being wrong about something.

Comment: Again, though, you're missing that the core of this solution is still a regular expression (in `.test`). And I don't see what "dynamic content with javascript" has to do with it..?!